# p-autoComplete Pre-select a default value

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-dropdowns

I am using p-autoComplete in a table, once a row is selected my auto complete should preselect the current value..I tried using [(ngModel)]="row.bsaName" but it is not working.
(Once I click on my dropwdown I see all the values, I confirmed the values do exist on my p-autoComplete dropdown)

also Note I used p-calendar which I was able to pre-select the current date once click on edit and not sure why auto complete is different

**hTML**

```
        <p-table #dt [value]="iBsaFollowup" dataKey="id" [paginator]="true" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,50,100]"
                     [rows]="10">

                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Followup DT</th>
                        <th>Comment</th>
                        <th>BSA Name</th>
                        <th>Action</th>

                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{row.ID}}</td>


                        <td>
                            <div *ngIf="!row.isBSAEditable">{{row.followupDate}}</div>
                            <div *ngIf="row.isBSAEditable">

                                <p-calendar name="followupDate" [(ngModel)]="row.followupDate"  [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar> <span style="margin-left:35px"></span>
                                <span *ngIf="isEmpty(row.comment)" style="color:crimson; font-size:8pt">Required</span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div *ngIf="!row.isBSAEditable">{{row.comment}}</div>
                            <div *ngIf="row.isBSAEditable">
                                                                       <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="row.comment" style="width:95%" maxlength="200">
                                <span *ngIf="isEmpty(row.comment)" style="color:crimson; font-size:8pt">Required</span>
                            </div>
                        </td>


                        <td>
                            <div *ngIf="!row.isBSAEditable">{{row.bsaName}}</div>
                            <div *ngIf="row.isBSAEditable">

                                <p-autoComplete name="bsaNameList" [(ngModel)]="row.bsaName" [suggestions]="iBsaList"   (completeMethod)="searchBsaList($event)" [style]="{'width':'85%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'85%'}" field="name" dataKey="id" [dropdown]="true"></p-autoComplete>

                                <span *ngIf="isEmpty(row.comment)" style="color:crimson; font-size:8pt">Required</span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <modal [row]="row" [disableEditSaveButton]='isEmpty(row.comment)' (deleteRow)="onDeleteToDoList(row)" [showModal]="!row.isBSAEditable" (selectedRow)="onSelectedFollowupdRow(row)" (cancelEdit)="onCancelEdit(row)" (save)="onSave(row)"></modal>
                            </div>
                            <!--<button (click)="editRow(row)">Edit</button>-->
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </ng-template>

            </p-table>
```

**component**

```
    bsaListVal: IBsaList;
    iBsaList: IBsaList[];
    originalBsaList: IBsaList[];
 searchBsaList(event) {
        this.iBsaList = this.originalBsaList;
        this.iBsaList = this.iBsaList
            .filter(data => data.name.toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(event.query.toString().toLowerCase()) !== -1);

    }
    GetBsaList() {
        this._dashboardService.getBSAList()
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.iBsaList = data.result;
                this.originalBsaList = data.result;

            },
            error => console.log('xx Method: ' + 'alert alert-danger'));

    }
```

**interface**

```
export interface IBsaList {

    id: string,
    name: string
}
```

********************************************UPDATE**********************************************
**HTML**

```
           <p-autoComplete name="bsaNameList" [(ngModel)]="row.bsaName" [suggestions]="bsaNameArr"   (completeMethod)="searchBsaList($event)" [style]="{'width':'85%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'85%'}" field="name" dataKey="id" [dropdown]="true"></p-autoComplete>
```

**Component**

```
        bsaListVal: IBsaList;
        iBsaList: IBsaList[];
        originalBsaList: string[];
        bsaNameArr: string[];
 searchBsaList(event) {
        this.bsaNameArr = this.originalBsaList;
        this.bsaNameArr = this.bsaNameArr
            .filter(data => data
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(event.query.toString().toLowerCase()) !== -1);

    }
    GetBsaList() {
        this._dashboardService.getBSAList()
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.bsaNameArr =  data.result.map(e => e.name);// data.result;
                this.originalBsaList = data.result.map(e => e.name);

            },
            error => console.log('GetAllAccessFor Method: ' + 'alert alert-danger'));

    }
```

Comment: The problem is `row.bsaName` is probably a `string` while the `autoComplete` is populated with `Array of Object` and you indicate the field to be `name`. Binding does not work because of this.

Comment: updated my above code..it is an array of strings...so how would I accomplish that

Comment: can you map your `IBsaList` to just `string[]`. Something like: `this.bsaNameArr = this.iBsaList.map(bsa => bsa.name)` then use `bsaNameArr` as the `[suggestions]` for your autoComplete

Comment: still not working..updated my above code

Comment: What does `data.result` return?

Comment: All{"result":[{"id":"VPXXXX","name":"XXX XXXX"},{"id":"VBXXXX","name":"VBXXXX"},{"id":"VAXXXXX","name":"XXXXX"},{"id":"VPXXXX","name":"XXXXXX"},{"id":"XXXXX","name":""},{"id":"VAXXXX","name":"XXXX XXXX"}]}

Comment: above is the result

Comment: if i use                                         <p-dropdown [options]="iBsaList" [(ngModel)]="row.bsaName" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown> it works even with my original code (the section before update) why auto-complete will be different?

Comment: Because optionLabel on Dropdown and field on AutoComplete do not work the same way. You can tell clearly is that `data.result` returns an array of object. Why would you assign both of your string[] to that array of object. I believe if you do `this.originalBsaList = data.result.map(e => e.name)` then `this.bsaNameArr = this.originalBsaList` would work

Comment: updated my above code...searchBsaList function ->.filter(data => data.name.toString()//error name does not exists

Comment: remove .name.toString()

Comment: updated my above code...now dropdown is empty no data

Comment: Oh man, you gotta remove the field property on your autoComplete as well o.O you sure you know what you’re doing?

Comment: yeah, thanks that works...not really I am new to this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to reconcile everything happened in the comments.

The reason why the `autocomplete` does not work as expected is because you're binding `[(ngModel)]` to a **string** `row.bsaName` while your `[suggestions]` is an **Array of Object**. Hence, binding does not work here. There are couple of ways to fix the issue:

1. Change `row.bsaName` or `bsaName` property on your data to an Object with `{id, name}` to match the data model of your `[suggestions]`
2. Make an **array of string** e.g: `bsaNamesArr: string[]` and on your data fetching, `map` over your `data.result` to get the `name array` and assign that to `bsaNamesArr` `this.bsaNamesArr = data.result.map(element => element.name)`. Now, use `bsaNamesArr` as the `[suggestions]` and also use `bsaNamesArr` in your `(completeMethod)` as well.

Make sure to remove the `field` property on your `p-autocomplete` if you use the 2nd approach.

Good luck!

Comment: one last question....how do I get the selected id not name from my auto complete dropdown. I do have a function that e the selected row, which is working but how d i get the selected id not name frm auto complete                                                                         onFollowupSave(row) {
       
      
           console.log("BSA UID " + this.bsaNameArr[row]);
          }

Comment: If you want to display name and get the id on selected, I’d suggest you go with the first approach to have access to the id and the name at the same time. However, you can get the id from the selectedName using Array.find() method.

Comment: ok, for simplicity I need to use option 1 as I have more logic based on selection..if I go with option one how would i bind ? excuse my ignorance in advance :)

Comment: @rgoal - You could always filter your arrays before doing the map to a simple array of strings.
`array.filter(a => a.prop1 == "condition1").map(element => element.prop1)`

Answer (score -2):

You can use,

```
 <ng-template></ng-template>
```

inside the

```
 <p-autoComplete></p-autoComplete>
```

tag as I have done in my project. Syntax below:

```
<p-autoComplete
     pTooltip="'tooltip'"
     [(ngModel)]="student"
     #student_id="ngModel"
     name="student_id"
     [suggestions]="studentsList"
     (completeMethod)="filterStudentsList($event)"
     field="name"
     [size]="30"
     placeholder="Enter Student name"
     [minLength]="1"
     required
     (onSelect)="onSelect($event)">
  <ng-template let-student pTemplate="item">
    {{ student.name }}
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-student pTemplate="selectedItem">
    {{ student.id }} {{ student.student_name }}
  </ng-template>
```

***So that if you want to select 2 values from selected suggestions we can do using this.***